# Unclaimed Network Realtek 8100

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, ethernet, realtek

Refreshing an older PC with Xubuntu 16.04 and failing to get a working wired Ethernet connection.

```
lspci -nn | grep 0200
02:0c.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
```

```
dmesg | grep -e 8139 -e eth0
[    0.139845] pci 0000:02:0c.0: [10ec:8139] type 00 class 0x020000
[    2.487928] 8139cp: 8139cp: 10/100 PCI Ethernet driver v1.3 (Mar 22, 2004)
[    2.487939] 8139cp 0000:02:0c.0: This (id 10ec:8139 rev 10) is not an 8139C+ compatible chip, use 8139too
[    2.551661] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
[    2.551916] 8139too 0000:02:0c.0: Chip not responding, ignoring board
[    2.564542] 8139too: probe of 0000:02:0c.0 failed with error -5
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: c
       bus info: pci@0000:02:0c.0
       version: 10
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=64 mingnt=32
       resources: ioport:9800(size=256) memory:feafbc00-feafbcff memory:feae0000-feaeffff
```

Cat5 cable plugged directly into router. Router lights show connected. PCI network card has one solid green LED lit.

Comment: "8139too 0000:02:0c.0: Chip not responding, ignoring board" Possibly helpful: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-247465-view-previous.html?sid=0c581ba623b48d5a5d829346120b6ba0 and also: https://yeri.be/realtek-ethernet-card-not-working-on-linux

Comment: Thanks for those links! I believe, as the links suggest, simply pulling the card and cleaning out dust or the contacts would have worked. In the end, due to timing, I swapped out the card with a different one and didn't see further problems.